# AWS lambda to firebase realtime db not updated

Tags: node.js, firebase, lambda, firebase-realtime-database

```
 'use strict';

var Firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
};

  if(Firebase.apps.length === 0) {
      Firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

exports.handler = function(event, context,callback) {

    try{
      var request = event.request;

      if(request.type === "LaunchRequest"){
        let options = {};
        options.speechText= "Welcome to TV. Using this skill you can control over 60 channels on your tv. To change to a different channel? You can say for example, play BBC Earth on tv";
        options.endSession= false;
        context.succeed(buildResponse(options));

      }else if(request.type ==="IntentRequest"){
        let options ={};
            if(request.intent.name === "ChannelIntent"){

               var message = 'hey guys';
               var ref = Firebase.database().ref().child("hello");
                var messagesRef = ref.child('messages');
                var messageRef = messagesRef.push(message);

                let ChannelName = request.intent.slots.ChannelName.value;
                options.speechText= "Channel changed to " +ChannelName+ ". ";
                options.endSession= true;
                context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
            }else{
                throw "unknown intent type";
            }

      }else if(request.type ==="SessionEndedRequest"){

      }else{
            throw "unknown intent type";
      }

    } catch(e){
      context.fail("Exception: "+e);
    }
}


function buildResponse(options){
  var response = {
    version: "1.0",
    response:{
      outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: options.speechText
      },
      shouldEndSession: options.endSession
    }
  };

  if(options.repromptText){
    response.reponse.reprompt ={
      outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: options.repromptText
      }
    };
  }
  return response;
}
```

The idea is to use alexa skill to control android tv app. firebase is used to connect alexa skill to the android tv app. The code runs successfully in AWS lambda but firebase db is not updated.
If someone has encountered similar issue and has found solution, please share the solution.

I will add code snippet of my aws lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Firebase operations are async, so you can't just assume success. You must wait for the call to complete:

```
messagesRef.push(message, (err) => {
  if (err) return context.fail(err);
  let ChannelName = request.intent.slots.ChannelName.value;
  options.speechText= "Channel changed to " +ChannelName+ ". ";
  options.endSession= true;
  context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
})
```